# Laravel Errors validation returning null

Tags: php, laravel

Yesterday I started with Laravel, currently busy with my first project, a simple news page.

Unfortunately, I've met some problems while validating my post request, I've tried to search on Google for my issue. And I tried to use those fixes, but strange enough I had no result.

The problem is:
When I post data the normal 'form page' will be shown without any errors. I'm aware that I have double error outputs, it's just for the test.

What do I want to reach?
I want that the validation error will be shown

[image: Image of page]

`routes.php`

```
<?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

Route::get('/', function() {
    return redirect()->route('home');
});

Route::get('/home', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@home',
]);

Route::get('/add_article', [
    'as' => 'add_article',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@add_article',
]);

Route::post('/add_article', [
    'as' => 'add_article.newarticle',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@post_article',
]);

});
```

`HomeController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\News;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

public function home(News $news) 
{
    $articles = $news->orderBy('id','desc')->take(3)->get();
    return view('home.home')->with('articles', $articles);
}

public function add_article()
{
    return view('home.add_article');
}

public function post_article(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:64',
        'content' => 'required|max:2048',
    ]);

    // $newNews = new News;
    // $newNews->title = $request->title;
    // $newNews->content = $request->content;
    // $newNews->save();
}

}
```

`add_article.blade.php`

```
@extends('templates.default')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6 offset-md-3 offset-lg-3 offset-xl-3">
            <p class="lead">New news article</p>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0"> </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('add_article.newarticle') }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="title" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                Title: 
                            </label>

                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Please enter your title!" id="title">
                            @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                {{ $errors->first('title') }}
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="content" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                                Content: 
                            </label>

                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="content" placeholder="Please enter your message!" id="content" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                            @if ($errors->has('content'))
                                {{ $errors->first('content') }}
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                                Create news
                            </button>
                        </div>

                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

I hope someone can help me to resolve this issue!

Comment: you want a validation message show in your page if anyone one submit the form without fill up data

Comment: what is dd($errors)

Comment: It's supposed to give an error alert if a field doesn't match the requirements.

Comment: dd($errors) means DieDumping the error object.

Comment: He means you need to DD($errors) to see what is returning. That way you can see if it is an issue on the server side with there actually being errors or if it is how you are displaying it. It will narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hello Kyle Wardle, thanks for your reply. When I do the DieDump I see no results since I get redirected back to the form page. I placed this dd($errors) within te post_article function below the validate part.

Comment: Have you tried `$request->validate([
       'title' => 'required|max:64',
       'content' => 'required|max:2048',
     ]);`

Comment: If I do it excactly your way and only change the field names it shows me 
BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
Method validate does not exist.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: I use the version  '5.2.45'

Comment: Within the view do something like `<?php dump($errors) ?>`

Comment: Okay, I've added the dump errors, while submitting the form I see this; https://i.imgur.com/smQRVqa.png

Comment: --- message removed ---

Comment: To be totally honest I am not sure. It looks ok to me. It looks like it is not returning any errors so that is somewhere to start but good luck finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\Http\Requests;
```

Remove This from **HomeController.php** and try.

Comment: Hello Md. Maruf Khan, thanks for your comment. The use App\Http\Requests; was already added to the HomeController, I've tried to remove $this and it will throw an exception; Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\validate()

Comment: I'm sorry, I've misread your comment. I've removed the use App\Http\Requests; from HomeController.php and it will still show a blank form page without any errors. https://i.imgur.com/zJjyiRv.png

Comment: Are you getting the form data in controller ? Try this`public function post_article(Request $request)
{

    dd($request->all());
}`

Comment: try diffrent key like "mytitle" ,"mycontent"

Comment: I´ve tried different keys like you told me, there´s no difference unfortunately..

Comment: I have no default.blade.php, I've removed that file since I don't need it.

Comment: So what's you **@extends**

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm quite new to Laravel. I though you meant the welcome page. Sorry here is the default.blade.php in the folder templates; https://i.imgur.com/G8LIFAx.png

Answer (score 0):

Based on those validation rules you will only see errors when the title is empty or longer than 64 characters, or the content is empty or longer than 2048 characters. Make sure the data you are testing with is long enough to trigger any errors.

For data that passes validation the code currently does not save (commented out), nor does it return a new location or view so it will show a blank page. You should probably save the data and redirect to the index or a show page with a success message.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is passing but you are not doing anything after so it's not going to show anything unless you tell it to.

Also make sure you use `$request->all()` instead of `$request` in the validator as the first one will return the actual input values that were submitted.

```
use Validator;


public function post_article(Request $request)
      {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|max:64',
            'content' => 'required|max:2048',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
                return redirect('home')
                            ->withErrors($validator)
                            ->withInput();
            }

        // $newNews = new News;
        // $newNews->title = $request->title;
        // $newNews->content = $request->content;
        // $newNews->save();

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'Article created.');

    }

    }
```

Then in your view add the following at the top:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            {{ Session::get('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif



@if (count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It gives me the same issue, just a blank page without alerts. (my form page) my code; https://pastebin.com/VEjQGbBA

Comment: Put a `dd('test')` inside your ` if ($validator->fails())` to see if its actually getting into it.

Comment: Yes it does, it gives me a "test"